# How to get each title lowest number in a multidimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get the lowest number in each title and in one array in JavaScript?

I hope able to get result only remain the lowest in each title like below,

```
 var result = [["Alex", "morning", 69],
               ["Terry", "morning", 127],
               ["Peter", "morning", 269]];
```

Thank You

```js
var value_array = [["Alex", "morning", 69],
                   ["Alex", "night", 537],
                   ["Terry", "Afternoon", 141],
                   ["Terry", "MidNight", 327],
                   ["Terry", "morning", 127],
                   ["Peter", "morning", 269]];
// I hope to filter each title(value_array[][0]) the lowest number(value_array[][2]) 
//Like the lowest for Alex(Title) is 69(lowest number).
//And the lowest for Terry(Title) is 127(lowest Number).
//And the lowest for Peter(Title) is 269(lowest Number).

// this is the format I try, but not working
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < value_array.length; i++) {

    for (var u = 0; u < value_array.length; u++) {

         if (value_array[i][0] == value_array[u][0]) {

              const numbers_arr = value_array[i][2];
              const add_arr = (a, b) => a + b;
           result.push(((numbers_arr.reduce(add_arr))/value_array.length).toFixed(0));

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: can you please show what have you tried till now?

Comment: is the last number always different, or could you have more than two itmes with the same number?

Comment: what is *title* and what is the lowest number and why do you wnat exactly the result, you wrote?

Comment: @RavindraThorat, I already key in what I have tried before. thanks

Comment: @Nina Scholz, yes the number always different, and it may come out same number

Comment: @Nina Scholz, the title is person name, and the lowest number is filter each person name his lowest number.  I want to get the lowest number in each person name. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hashtable to find duplicate names, then compare the value:

```js
 const value_array = [["Alex", "morning", 69], ["Alex", "night", 537], ["Terry", "Afternoon", 141], ["Terry", "MidNight", 327], ["Terry", "morning", 127], ["Peter", "morning", 269]];


 const result = [], hash = {};

 for(const [name, time, value] of value_array) {
   if(hash[name]) {
     if(hash[name][2] > value) {
       hash[name][1] = time;
       hash[name][2] = value;
    }
  } else {
    result.push(hash[name] = [name, time, value]);
  }
}

 console.log(result);
```

Alternatively you could sort the array by name and then by descending value, then filter out all duplicate names:

```js
 const value_array = [["Alex", "morning", 69], ["Alex", "night", 537], ["Terry", "Afternoon", 141], ["Terry", "MidNight", 327], ["Terry", "morning", 127], ["Peter", "morning", 269]];

 value_array.sort(([nameA, , valueA], [nameB, , valueB]) =>
   nameA.localeCompare(nameB) ||
   valueA - valueB
);

 let dupe = "";
 const result = value_array.filter(([name]) => name !== dupe && (dupe = name));

 console.log(result);
```

Comment: @the editor I'm sorry, we commited at the same time and the snippet got lost :(

Comment: That's completely fine. I was just trying to understand your code then finally added to the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce function and create an object & then use the Object.values to get the value from that object

```js
var value_array = [
  ["Alex", "morning", 69],
  ["Alex", "night", 537],
  ["Terry", "Afternoon", 141],
  ["Terry", "MidNight", 327],
  ["Terry", "morning", 127],
  ["Peter", "morning", 269],
  ["Peter", "morning", 20]
];

let m = value_array.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
 //check if the object has key by name Alex,Peter ..
 // if not then create a key by the name and assign the value to it
 // Ex {Alex:["Alex", "morning", 69]}
  if (acc[curr[0]] === undefined) {
    acc[curr[0]] = curr
  } else {
    // if it has a key then check the number & compare
    // if it is less the than the current then replace it 
    if (acc[curr[0]][2] > curr[2]) {
      acc[curr[0]] = curr
    }

  }
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(m))
```